# I'm trying to create JSON from a comma delimited array

Tags: php, json

**I need to output like this.**

```
{"name":"","lat":"28.619284999999998","lng":"77.02616189999999"},{"name":"","lat":"28.619284999999998","lng":"77.02616189999999"},{"name":"","lat":"28.619284999999998","lng":"77.02616189999999"},{"name":"","lat":"28.619284999999998","lng":"77.02616189999999"},{"name":"","lat":"28.619284999999998","lng":"77.02616189999999"},{"name":"","lat":"28.619284999999998","lng":"77.02616189999999"},{"name":"","lat":"28.6192875","lng":"77.0261699"},{"name":"","lat":"28.6192887","lng":"77.02616139999999"},{"name":"","lat":"28.6192887","lng":"77.02616139999999"},{"name":"","lat":"28.6192887","lng":"77.02616139999999"},{"name":"","lat":"28.6192887","lng":"77.02616139999999"},{"name":"","lat":"28.6236227","lng":"77.0317984"},{"name":"","lat":"28.6244627","lng":"77.0322383"},{"name":"","lat":"28.6245415","lng":"77.0331425"},{"name":"","lat":"28.6245418","lng":"77.0331053"},{"name":"","lat":"28.6246156","lng":"77.0322415"},{"name":"","lat":"28.6242647","lng":"77.0316073"}
```

**PHP Script**

```
$sql="SELECT name,lat,lng FROM `in_point_creation` WHERE 1";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $json_array = json_encode($row);
  print_r($json_array);
}
```

**Current Output**

```
{"name":"","lat":"28.619284999999998","lng":"77.02616189999999"}{"name":"","lat":"28.619284999999998","lng":"77.02616189999999"}{"name":"","lat":"28.619284999999998","lng":"77.02616189999999"}{"name":"","lat":"28.619284999999998","lng":"77.02616189999999"}{"name":"","lat":"28.619284999999998","lng":"77.02616189999999"}{"name":"","lat":"28.619284999999998","lng":"77.02616189999999"}{"name":"","lat":"28.6192875","lng":"77.0261699"}{"name":"","lat":"28.6192887","lng":"77.02616139999999"}{"name":"","lat":"28.6192887","lng":"77.02616139999999"}{"name":"","lat":"28.6192887","lng":"77.02616139999999"}{"name":"","lat":"28.6192887","lng":"77.02616139999999"}{"name":"","lat":"28.6236227","lng":"77.0317984"}{"name":"","lat":"28.6244627","lng":"77.0322383"}{"name":"","lat":"28.6245415","lng":"77.0331425"}{"name":"","lat":"28.6245418","lng":"77.0331053"}{"name":"","lat":"28.6246156","lng":"77.0322415"}{"name":"","lat":"28.6242647","lng":"77.0316073"}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create the entire object you need before calling JSON encode:

```
$sql="SELECT name,lat,lng FROM `in_point_creation` WHERE 1";
$result=mysql_query($sql); //You need to switch to mysqli , mysql is no longer a valid choice
$json_array = [];
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $json_array[] = $row;
}
$jsonString = json_encode($json_array);
print_r($jsonString);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to solve your "problem".

But first, don't use mysql_* functions => [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)
Use mysqli_* functions instead.

If you have just a few hundred rows, you maybe could build an array with all items, like Paul Crovella and apokryfos said.
But if there are a multiple thousands of rows, you should prefer to write them out as quick as possible and don't save them to your RAM. Because PHP has limited space in RAM.

Maybe you could try it without loop:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('host','username','password','database')
$query = 'SELECT name,lat,lng FROM `in_point_creation` WHERE 1';
$result = $conn->query($query);
$data = mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($data);
```